# JavaScript placing the input.question inside the Number function?

Tags: javascript, function, numbers

Using the Number function can I change the below input.question into a number on the same line?  I know I can use console.log and convert num1 to a Number but I'm wondering if I can put the input.question into the number function?

```js
const input = require(`readline-sync`);
let num1 = input.question("Enter a number: ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```js
const input = require(`readline-sync`);
let num1 = Number(input.question("Enter a number: "))
```

Although are many ways to convert a string to a number, one of the easier way is to add a `+` before the `string`. Like this:

```js
const input = require(`readline-sync`);
let num1 = +input.question("Enter a number: ");
```

Comment: Calling `Number()` is much better because it's more explicit and easier to undrestand. We're not code-golfing here :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yea that's true, `Number()` makes more sense, but it's not bad to use such tricks if you understand how and y that works. 